# How to spread an object to a function as arguments?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I have an object an a function which accept arguments, I would like to spread the objects so each property is an argument in that function.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
const args = {
    a: 1
    b: 2
}

const fn = (a, b) => a + b

// i am trying with no success
console.log(fn(...args))
```

Comment: you cannot use the `...` spread syntax in your case, because you are not using it with something iterable (like an array)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use ES6 [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on passed parameter and then just pass your object.

```js
const args = {a: 1, b: 2}

const fn = ({a, b}) => a + b
console.log(fn(args))
```

You can also set default values for those properties.

```js
const args = {b: 2}

const fn = ({a = 0, b = 0}) => a + b
console.log(fn(args))
```

Comment: And for arrays?

Answer (score 78):

Although the other answers are correct, they change the function signature to accept an object instead of 2 separate arguments. Here is how to use an object's values as function arguments without altering the function's signature. This requires `Object.values` (ES 2017) and the spread operator to be available in your runtime.

```
const args = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

const fn = (a, b) => a + b

fn(...Object.values(args));
```

Keep in mind this will work only in your specific case, since `Object.values` returns the values of all object keys and doesn't guarantee alphabetical sort order. If you want to take only the values of properties which are named `a` and `b`, you can map over `Object.keys(args)` and filter only those values.

Comment: That's certainly more along the lines of what I was looking for when I arrived at this question.  Thank you.

Comment: The order of key is not deterministic. so sometimes a might get b's values and vice versa.

Comment: @GolakSarangi, this is written in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I get : ` A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. [2556]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
const fn = ({a, b}) => a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are certainly applicable in particular situations, still have some  limitations as well. Therefore I'd like to propose a different approach. The idea is to add to the object a method that returns an array of desired parameters in the appropriate order. That method is executed when passed to target function as argument and result destructured with spread operator.

```
const args = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    argumentify: function () { 
        return [this.a, this.b]; 
    }
};

const fn = (a, b) => a + b;

console.log(fn(...args.argumentify()));
```

Benefits of this approach:

1) Does not require changes of the target function's signature, so can be used to ANY function.

2) Guarantees correct order of parameters (which is (as I understand) not guaranteed when spreading object).

3) Can itself be parametrized if needed.