# Pass in params to function by object spreading a params object not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to pass in all the params to this function by spreading a params object [like this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008728/3935156):

```
public showToast(
    content: string,
    buttonLabel = 'Ok',
    hideDelay?: number,
    buttonAction?: Function,
    uniqueKey?: string,
    canBeCleared?: boolean,
    templateCtrl?: Object
): Toast {
    const toast = new Toast(
        content,
        this,
        buttonLabel,
        hideDelay,
        buttonAction,
        uniqueKey,
        canBeCleared,
        templateCtrl
    );
    toast.id = !this.lastToast ? 1 : this.lastToast.id + 1;
    this.toasts.push(toast);
    toast.top = toast.fromTop;

    // hiding is handled in the ToastComponent
    return toast;
}
```

My attempt:

```
const toastArgs = {
    content: 'test toast',
    buttonLabel: 'test button',
    hideDelay: 1000,
    buttonAction: () => 5,
    uniqueKey: 'uk',
    canBeCleared: true,
    templateCtrl: { strl: 3 }
};
service.showToast(...Object.values(toastArgs));
```

The compile time error:

> Expected 1-7 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
> toast.service.ts(18, 9): An argument for 'content' was not provided.

Why do I get this error? I have followed the SO answer.

Comment: The full error message, compiler options, and the version of TypeScript maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this since `Object.values(toastArgs)` gets inferred as:

```js
(true | "test toast" | "test button" | 1000 | (() => number) | "uk" | {
    readonly strl: 3;
})[]
```

Typescript does not really have the concept of an array's 'length'. As far as typescript is concerned, `toastArgs` could be `{ x: true }`, and it would satisfy the type of `Object.values(toastArgs)`. You can test this out like so:

```js
const toastArgsValid = {
  content: 'test toast',
  buttonLabel: 'test button',
  hideDelay: 1000,
  buttonAction: () => 5,
  uniqueKey: 'uk',
  canBeCleared: true,
  templateCtrl: {strl: 3},
};

const toastArgsValuesValid = Object.values(toastArgsValid);

type ToastParamsValid = typeof toastArgsValuesValid;

const toastArgsInvalid = {
  x: true,
};

const toastArgsValuesInvalid: ToastParamsValid = Object.values(
  toastArgsInvalid,
); // No error here since the invalid type is a subtype of the valid type
```

One way to achieve what you're looking for is to refactor your `showToast` method to instead take a single object, instead of positional args:

```js
public showToast({
  content,
  buttonLabel,
  hideDelay,
  buttonAction,
  uniqueKey,
  canBeCleared,
  templateCtrl,
}: {
  content: string;
  buttonLabel: string;
  hideDelay?: number;
  buttonAction?: Function;
  uniqueKey?: string;
  canBeCleared?: boolean;
  templateCtrl?: Object;
}): Toast {
 // function body
}
```

You can then call:

```js
service.showToast(toastArgs)
```

Alternatively you can also use a type assertion, without refactoring your code like so:

```js
service.showToast(...(Object.values(toastArgs) as Parameters<typeof service.showToast>));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values()` is supported from es2017, [ECMAScript_2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla). And the default target version of TypeScript is `ES3`. The error can be fixed by just adding the [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `--target es2017`.