# How to spread an object as individual arguments in a function whose declaration I cannot change?

Tags: javascript, function, destructuring

I have an object with some properties such as;

```js
integrationConfig = {
  iconEmoji: ':myIconEmoji:', 
  team: 'myTeam', 
  text: 'myText', 
  channel: 'myChannel', 
  botName: 'myBot'
}
```

I am passing this object to a function below as shown (`attachments` is not important).

```js
return await this.pushToSlack(...integrationConfig, attachments);
```

Importantly, this function is part of an NPM Package, so **I don’t want to change the function declaration**.

The function is declared like this:

```js
exports.pushToSlack = function (channel, text, botName, iconEmoji, team, attachments, cb = function () {}) {
  // […]
}
```

I put some breakpoint to the `pushToSlack` function but the debugger didn’t jump into that line. I guess the function is not called somehow. I also receive this error:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
```

Have you got any idea?

Comment: Why not `function (integrationConfig, attachments, cb = function () {})` - it makes more sense

Comment: You may need to declare your object as Array of object or list

Comment: That function is written inside npm package thats why I am trying to fit my object according to these params :(

Comment: Related: [how to spread an object to a function as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48008539/4642212).

Comment: There are some fundamentally incorrect assertions in your question. But the most relevant has to do with the order of arguments in your function call. The spread operator can only be the last argument in the call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread syntax is not usable for that
use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
integrationConfig = 
  { iconEmoji : ':myIconEmoji:'
  , team      : 'myTeam'
  , text      : 'myText'
  , channel   : 'myChannel'
  , botName   : 'myBot'
  }
```

the call :

```
return await this.pushToSlack( integrationConfig, attachments);
```

the function :

```
 exports.pushToSlack = function ({channel, text, botName, iconEmoji, team}, attachments, ...
 //..Destructuring assignment....^.......................................^
 // Arguments can be in any order you want
 // and no obligation to have all of them
```

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change the parameter list of the function, you’ll have to define the order the arguments are expected in, then map your object onto this order:

```js
const argumentOrder = [
    "channel",
    "text",
    "botName",
    "iconEmoji",
    "team"
  ];

// […]

return await this.pushToSlack(...argumentOrder.map((property) => integrationConfig[property]), attachments);
```

The error you’re getting means that `func(...integrationConfig)` won’t work. Yes, the function is never called. There’s a distinction between object spread and iterable spread. Arguments and arrays use iterable spread, which means that two conditions must be met: firstly, the value you want to spread must be [non-nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish); and secondly, **the value must be iterable**, i.e. something that has [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). Object spread only checks the first condition.

You could, theoretically, add such a symbol property into your object, which would allow you to use your original syntax:

```js
const integrationConfig = {
    iconEmoji: ":myIconEmoji:",
    team: "myTeam",
    text: "myText",
    channel: "myChannel",
    botName: "myBot",
    *[Symbol.iterator](){
      yield this.channel;
      yield this.text;
      yield this.botName;
      yield this.iconEmoji;
      yield this.team;
    }
  };

// […]

return await this.pushToSlack(...integrationConfig, attachments);
```

Comment: @berkinakaydin You may be able to use your original `return await this.pushToSlack(...integrationConfig, attachments);` syntax. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

so you have function

```
const pushToSlack = function (channel, text, botName, iconEmoji, team, attachments, cb = function () {}) {
```

this function accepts 7 arguments.

You have good idea to spread an object `integrationConfig`, hoping that it will become 7 arguments.

However spreading an object will just clone the exact same object with exact same property.

`const obj = {...integrationConfig}` is equal to `ONE` Object.

You can instead pass an array and spread it.

`pushToSlack(...Object.values(integrationConfig))`
But an object does not guarantee the order of the key. so it could be

```
// order is not guaranteed!!!
...Object.values(integrationConfig) === [botName, channel, iconEmoji, team, text] 
// or
...Object.values(integrationConfig) === [channel, botName, iconEmoji, team, text] 
// or 
...Object.values(integrationConfig) === [team, botName, iconEmoji, channel, text]
```

However your function need a fix order of arguments.

1. channel as first argument,
2. text as second argument
3. etc.

I believe you can do like this

```
const integrationConfig = {
        iconEmoji: ':myIconEmoji:', 
        team: 'myTeam', 
        text: 'myText', 
        channel: 'myChannel', 
        botName: 'myBot'
    }

const {iconEmoji, team, text, channel, botName} = integrationConfig

pushToSlack(channel, text, botName, iconEmoji, team, etc);
```

Comment: Please, do not use code markup for things that are not code. Other than that, the suggestion using `const {iconEmoji, team, text, channel, botName} = integrationConfig` is almost good… the syntax is clean, but you’ll have to keep five new variables around.